# Take ownership greyed out

Tags: security, permissions, privacy, windows-defender, ownership

I am the system administrator.
I took ownership of those directories:
C:\Windows
C:\Program Files
C:\Program Files (x86)
I gave myself full permissions without any problems.
Recently i noticed an .exe becoming more and more active in task manager than normally.
After installing windows this exe was almost never active now it is a few minutes after booting windows.

I am speaking about the windows defender.
MpCopyAccelerator.exe
MpCmdRun.exe

When i use the `sc stop` command i get an error:
`The specified service is not an installed service`

However the specified service is in fact an installed service.

Anyways back to topic, i became upset with this service since i have no insight what it really does.
I'm not going to harm my PC by doing anything stupid, i simply want to be able to end the task whenever i want to.
Taking ownership of the file or the directory does not work as the title says, everything is greyed out even for administrator.
Is there a command i can use with powershell or cmd to give myself full permissions or change the owner?

I'm sure there is such a command, so thanks already for sharing it.

See screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Comment: how do i edit the question? saw a spelling mistake in first line...

Comment: There's an edit button in the row of links at the bottom of the question. I've taken the liberty of fixing that typo and doing some other assorted changes, like putting your images inline

Comment: By taking ownership of sensitive Windows folders you have already harmed your PC. There's a good chance that you will need to reinstall Windows.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason why some files are protected, even for Administrators. As you can see below, this is the expected behavior for this file as Administrators cannot take ownership:

[image: Ownership Privilege 1]

But to answer your question, you can change the ownership of such files and folders easily. **Simply restart Windows in Safe Mode** and you will be able make any changes you want.

For example, the Ownership of this file has been changed from SYSTEM to Administrators in Safe Mode. After rebooting back into Normal Mode, here is the result:

[image: Ownership Privilege 2]